# R Package Error error: ‘std::Rf_beta’ has not been declared #define beta Rf_beta

Tags: c++, r, c, gcc

I am trying to install an R package called `dbarts`. I am running R on a rhel8 linux machine. But I am seeing the following error during install.

I already installed rhel8 linux packages gcc, clang, and clang-devel.

```
> install.packages('dbarts', lib = .Library.site)
trying URL 'https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/2023-07-12/src/contrib/dbarts_0.9-23.tar.gz'
Content type 'binary/octet-stream' length 850972 bytes (831 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 831 KB

* installing *source* package ‘dbarts’ ...
** package ‘dbarts’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++17 accepts -g... yes
checking for g++ -std=gnu++17 option to enable C++11 features... none needed
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -std=gnu++17 -E
checking for C/C++ restrict keyword... no
checking for stdio.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for C compiler vendor... gnu
checking whether C compiler accepts ... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -msse2... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -msse4.1... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -mavx... yes
checking whether C compiler accepts -mavx2... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking whether gcc is Clang... no
checking whether pthreads work with "-pthread" and "-lpthread"... yes
checking for joinable pthread attribute... PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE
checking whether more special flags are required for pthreads... no
checking for PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT... yes
checking for cstdint... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking for int64_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking size of size_t... 8
checking alignment of void*... 8
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for clock_gettime... yes
checking for ffs... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for working alloca.h... yes
checking for alloca... yes
checking for working posix_memalign... yes
checking for snprintf... yes
checking if g++ supports namespace std... yes
checking whether snprintf is in std::... yes
checking for log1p... yes
checking whether log1p is in std::... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
config.status: creating src/config.hpp
config.status: creating src/dbarts/config.hpp
config.status: creating src/misc/config.h
config.status: creating src/external/config.h
config.status: creating inst/include/dbarts/types.hpp
config.status: creating src/include/misc/types.h
** libs
using C compiler: ‘gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18)’
using C++ compiler: ‘g++ (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18)’
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -Iinclude -pthread  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c R_C_interface.cpp -o R_C_interface.o
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -Iinclude -pthread  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c R_interface.cpp -o R_interface.o
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -Iinclude -pthread  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c R_interface_common.cpp -o R_interface_common.o
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -Iinclude -pthread  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -g -O2  -c R_interface_crossvalidate.cpp -o R_interface_crossvalidate.o
In file included from include/external/stats.h:10,
                 from R_interface_crossvalidate.cpp:13:
/opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R/include/Rmath.h:210:15: error: ‘std::Rf_beta’ has not been declared
 #define beta  Rf_beta
               ^~~~~~~
make: *** [/opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:200: R_interface_crossvalidate.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dbarts’
* removing ‘/opt/R/4.3.1/lib/R/site-library/dbarts’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/opt/rtemp/Rtmpzomc18/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("dbarts", lib = .Library.site) :
  installation of package ‘dbarts’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Try a quick `grep` in the `src/` directory. It looks a symbol std::Rf_beta was not found, and that makes sense as Rf_beta is a plain C function provided by the C API of R, and not part of the std namespace in C++.

Comment: The package is clean at CRAN though: https://cloud.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_dbarts.html  So that points to something at your end. Did you by chance change `~/.R/Makevars`?  Or maybe g++ 8.5.0 is too old.  For what it is worth the package installs fine for me (Ubuntu 23.04, g++ 12.3.0).

Answer (score 2):

The error feels like it could be an incompatibility between R's `stats` headers and the C / C++ library headers.

Since C++17, `std::beta()` is now defined as described in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_functions/beta. I'm guessing that this line in the R sources:

https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/09c2fbdcab3fd4397e4e654f21222687ed71ef4b/src/include/Rmath.h0.in#L210

is what's causing trouble. Fortunately, you should be able to dodge the issue with something like:

```
#define R_NO_REMAP
#define R_NO_REMAP_RMATH
```

which could be included in the package's `src/Makevars` file, or alternatively, within your own `~/.R/Makevars` file. (You may need to create that file if it does not already exist.)

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error while installing `tgp` package.
The culprit was including `math.h` after `Rmath.h`.
As for `dbarts` version 0.9-23, the solution is

- adding `#include <math.h>` before `#include <external/stats.h>` on line 13 or
- comment out `#include <math.h>` on line 40.